# Returning results with matching first characters from stored procedure in mySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have added a DocumentListener to a JTextField, searchField, so that a stored procedure is called each time the user types in or deletes a character in searchField.

I would like the stored procedure to return rows where the value in a column matches the typed in characters and their order. Say I have a table.column FirstName with value "Pete". If the user types in "P", it should return "Pete", if the user types in "Pe", it should return "Pete" and so forth. But if the user just type in "e" it shouldn't return "Pete". I know there might be performance issues here, but the table is unlikely to contain more than 5000 rows, so I guess that won't be a problem.

So far I have something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE search (IN something VARCHAR(45))
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM Folks
WHERE FirstName LIKE CONCAT("%", something, "%")
END;
```

However, it only returns everyone by the name of let's say "Pete", but does not return everyone starting with "P", "Pe" and so forth. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
WHERE FirstName LIKE CONCAT(something, "%")
```

Leave out the `%` at the beginning, so it has to match the beginning exactly.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I can see that it should work, and I've also tried changing my where-clause in the procedure to WHERE FirstName Like CONCAT("p", "%") and that works. However, WHERE FirstName LIKE CONCAT(something, "%") does not give me the same result. I guess it means that the "error" is somewhere else?